# Can I only strip debug information for local symbols only from ELF?

Tags: local, elf, strip, debug-symbols

Our building system generates very large executable files.
Many size of the executable is debug information. so strip may reduce the executable size notably. but if all debug information stripped, debug will be hard.

So, I want to know, is there any way to strip local debug information only? such as local variables, function parameters. I need to keep the relationship between function name and file line to enable gdb backtrace and up/down command work.

Great thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to keep the relationship between function name and file line to enable gdb backtrace and up/down command work.

You are mistaken: `backtrace` and `up/down` work fine *without any* debug info at all. If `backtrace` is *all* you need, then simply build without any debug flags, and you'll be fine.

If you really do need file info, and *if* you are compiling with a recent `gcc` (or `g++`) and use `DWARF`, then you may want:

```
      -gsplit-dwarf
       Separate as much dwarf debugging information as possible into a
       separate output file with the extension .dwo.  This option
       allows the build system to avoid linking files with debug
       information.  To be useful, this option requires a debugger
       capable of reading .dwo files.
```

Note: this still leaves file/line info in the main binary, but leaves everything else in the `.dwo` files.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
strip --strip-debug

Also try

```
   -g
   -S
   -d
```